# split string and average by matching lines in awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to output the count of the matching `$4` values with the text in `$5` before the `-` and the average of the matching `$7`. The output is sorted so that the matching `$5` strings are grouped together. The `awk` is close but the output is empty and there probably is a better way, but hopefully is is a start :).  Thank you :).

**input**

```
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543-955763  AGRN-6|gc=75    1   25
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543-955763  AGRN-6|gc=75    2   25
chr1    1167809 1168658 chr1:1167809-1168658    B3GALT6-42|gc=75.8  1   2
chr1    1167809 1168658 chr1:1167809-1168658    B3GALT6-42|gc=75.8  2   2
chr1    1167809 1168658 chr1:1167809-1168658    B3GALT6-42|gc=75.8  3   2
chr1    976035  976270  chr1:976035-976270  AGRN-9|gc=74.5  228 28
chr1    976035  976270  chr1:976035-976270  AGRN-9|gc=74.5  229 28
chr1    976035  976270  chr1:976035-976270  AGRN-9|gc=74.5  230 27
```

**desired output** (matching `$4` split of `$5` with average of `$7` sorted by `$5`)

```
chr1:955543-955763  2 AGRN  25  
chr1:976035-976270  3 AGRN  27
chr1:1167809-1168658 3 B3GALT6  2
```

**awk**

```
awk '
function file_print() {
for(k in a) {
split(k, ks, / |(-[0-9]*[|])/)
printf("%s %d %s %d\n", ks[1], c[k], ks[2], a[k] / c[k]) > ofn
delete a[k]
delete c[k]
}
close(ofn)
}
NR > 1 && FNR == 1 {
file_print()
}
FNR == 1 {
ofn = substr(FILENAME, 1, length(FILENAME))
}
{   a[k = $4 " " $5] += $7
c[k]++
}
END {   file_print()
}' input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating the task.

If I understand your requirement, this produces the output (in slightly different order):

```
awk '{seen[$4]++; sub(/-.*/, "", $5); field[$4]=$5; sum[$4]+=$7} 
      END{for (e in seen) print e, seen[e], field[e], int(sum[e]/seen[e])}' file

chr1:1167809-1168658 3 B3GALT6 2
chr1:976035-976270 3 AGRN 27
chr1:955543-955763 2 AGRN 25
```

You can then run it through `sort` to groups and sort by `$5` like so:

```
awk '{seen[$4]++; sub(/-.*/, "", $5); field[$4]=$5; sum[$4]+=$7} 
      END{for (e in seen) print e, seen[e], field[e], int(sum[e]/seen[e])}' file | sort -k 2

chr1:955543-955763 2 AGRN 25
chr1:976035-976270 3 AGRN 27
chr1:1167809-1168658 3 B3GALT6 2
```

Comment: Thank you both very much... I was definitely overcomplicating things :).

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{split($5,f,"-"); k=$4 OFS f[1]; s[k]+=$NF; c[k]++}
    END{for(k in s) print k, c[k], int(s[k]/c[k])}' file

chr1:955543-955763 AGRN 2 25
chr1:976035-976270 AGRN 3 27
chr1:1167809-1168658 B3GALT6 3 2
```

note the order is slightly different since $5 prefix is part of the key as well.  Also the average is rounded down as in your example.  If you need to rearrange, just pipe to `... | awk '{t=$2;$2=$3;$3=t}1'` to swap two fields.